# Can not get error message spring security 4 custom login form

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

i,m using spring security 4.4 and following jsp to login.when password or user name is wrong it reload this page without any error message.

```html
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">
   
   <!--   <http pattern="/loginpage" security="none"/> -->

    <http use-expressions="true">
      <intercept-url pattern="/loginpage" access="isAnonymous()"/>
     <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
     <form-login login-page="/loginpage" default-target-url="/index" authentication-failure-url="/loginpage" />

     <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/index"/>

       
    </http>
 
   <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
  <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"></beans:property>
   </beans:bean>
   <beans:bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <beans:constructor-arg>    
     <beans:list>
    <beans:ref bean="daoAuthenticationProvider"/>
     </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
  </beans:bean>
  <authentication-manager>
   <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
    <password-encoder hash="md5"></password-encoder>
   </authentication-provider>
  </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Registration Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Input Your Detail</h2>
<form name='f'action="login" method='POST'>
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
 <table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>User Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="username" size="30" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" size="30" /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="login" /></td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
    </table>
</form>


<c:if test="${param.error != null}"> 
 <p>Invalid username or password</p>
</c:if>
</body>
</html>
```

Are there any security xml con figurations to get error message?

Comment: You have to post some code snippet of controller layer.

Comment: i post my security xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `authentication-failure-url="/loginpage"` 
to

```
authentication-failure-url="/loginpage?error=true"
```

in spring-security.xml
It works.

Comment: Any way to get a custom error message into your failure url?